# FabricJS include all attributes in canvas.toObject()

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

When saving a canvas using `canvas.toObject()`, custom object attributes are skipped, but also some build in ones such as: `borderColor`. This can be quite annoying since saving the canvas using `canvas.toObject()` and loading it again using `loadFromJson()` can load something that is not the same.

Luckily there is a solution to define properties that should be included in `canvas.toObject()` which I found in a separate SO thread:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
    return function (propertiesToInclude) {
        propertiesToInclude = (propertiesToInclude || []).concat(
          ['uuid','rt_attributes']
        );
        return toObject.apply(this, [propertiesToInclude]);
    };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

But however, since in my use case there are a lot of properties to include, I am wondering if there is a way to just include all object attributes when running `canvas.toObject()`, or in other words, is it possible to disable this filter?

My side question is if anyone knows where I can find this list of attributes that gets ignored when running `canvas.toObject()`?

Thanks

Comment: To answer the second, http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line14920.  To answer the first, it's pretty insistent on its defaults and a list of properties from the user, mostly because there are some things which can be directly copied and some things which must have `toObject` called on them before being added to the final object.  You could take the list of properties from that function and then exclude all those props from `Object.keys` before invoking `toObject`.